# Set Axis Tick Labels in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

My input to gnuplot looks something like this:

```
1:00am  1       10
1:00am  30      12
1:01am  60      18
1:01am  90      20
1:02am  120     21
...
```

The first column contains (what I'd like to be) the X-axis labels, while the second column contains the X-axis values. (In actual point of fact, I have one row per second, so many rows have '1:00am' as in the label column, then '1:01am', etc).

I can plot the values I care about using something like:

```
gnuplot> plot "my_data.txt" using 2:3 with lines
```

And I can set the X axis to have a tick (and label) every 30 minutes (which is 30 * 60 = 1800 seconds), but the label it uses is the X axis value (something like 3600 for one hour).

What I can't get is for the *labels* that show up under each tick to use the values from the first column. I can't even find anything that looks promising in the gnuplot manual. I've got to assume this is possible, I just don't know where to look.

**Edit:**

Progress, I've discovered the `xticlabels()` parameter to `plot`. The problem is that it seems to plot these labels for every xtic (that is, one per second in my data set), rather than at the intervals defined by `set xtics`.

**Edit and Answer:**

Turns out `gnuplot` has support for graphing time-series data. For the curious:

```
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set xdata time
```

This causes the X axis data (once reformatted to match that pattern) to be interpreted as time-series data. This is then combined with

```
set xtics 3600
```

Formats the X axis as I described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry caught this late, but yes was to suggest `set timefmt ... ; set xdata time`.  I always pass in my time format as `%s` but just as a common practice.

Comment: Yup, that was the solution I used. I'll check the answer even though it was a little late :-P

Comment: Thanks! :)  Forgot to add gnuplot as a personal tag :)